# In what language is there a "guard" keyword or concept?

Tags: c++, class, nomenclature

I recently tried to understand a C++ program that was written by somebody who I assume had a background in functional programming: For example, he had declared a **closure** class which he extensively used and which does somewhat resemble what is known as a closure in functional programming. Another class was called a **guard**, but I haven't quite figured out yet what it is good for. It seems to have some sort of cleanup functionality attached to it.

The only language in which I have seen a concept called **guard** is Erlang, but that does not remotely look similar to the code I found. In what other languages does such a concept exist that the author of the C++ code may have alluded to?

Comment: Could you give an example of usage?

Comment: In C++ a **guard variable** is a thread-safe boolean to ensure a static variable is initialized exactly once (similar in concept to Singleton), which is entirely different from "guards" in functional languages which is similar to **conditionals**. But since this name is from custom classes it's hard to tell which function it refers to.

Comment: AraK: Sorry, I can't post any code. One thing I can say that it clearly has nothing to do with the mechanism for specifying conditions in Erlang or Haskell.

Comment: This question is useless without code

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To me it sounds like he was using RAII.
The class constructor/destructor is used to symetrically handle some form of resource allocation/release in an exception safe context (What Java programmers would call finally {} as the destructor is guranteed to be called.).

This is a very common C++ idiom and is ued extensively in modern C++.

Did the code look like this:

```
void Plop()
{
     Guard   guard(lock);
     // Do lots of stuff
}
```

Here the guard is locking the lock in the constructor and unlocking the lock in the destructor.

Comment: +1 I suspect this is the actual correct answer. The functional stuff is probably a red herring.

Comment: If you mean "Resource Allocation Is Initialization" you are almost certainly right. Thanks! I'm still not quite sure what the word `guard` alludes to, though.

Comment: It guards against exceptions causing problems!

Answer (score 6):

The term "guard" is used in [several functional languages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guard_%28computing%29) the way it is used in Erlang, but that usage doesn't seem to fit your description. Without seeing the C++ code it's hard to really know what was intended by it.

A guess by your description would be that it implements something like Haskell's [`bracket`](http://haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base-4.2.0.0/Control-Exception.html#v:bracket), which basically ensures that some resources are released if the wrapped function exits, even if that happened by an exception. In Python one would use `finally` for this, in C++ you usually have the cleanup code in the destructor of an object on the stack.

Answer (score 4):

In general terms, a *guard* is simply a construct which needs to evaluate to true for execution along some path to continue. This or something like it exists in all useful Turing-complete programming languages, but is perhaps so basic that is often not named separately as an entity. Here's a simple example in Haskell:

```
f x
 | x < 0 = -x
 | otherwise = x
```

This is equivalent to the absolute value function: negate a number if it's negative to produce its positive counterpart; otherwise, return the same value passed in. There are two guards here: `x < 0`, which is true when x is less than zero, and `otherwise`, which is always true.

Answer (score 3):

Haskell's Control.Monad module has [`guard`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/6.12.1/html/libraries/base-4.2.0.0/Control-Monad.html#v%3Aguard):

> **`guard :: MonadPlus m => Bool -> m ()`**
>   `guard b` is `return ()` if `b` is `True`, and `mzero` if `b` is `False`.

For example, to compute Pythagorean triples where each leg is no longer than 25, you could use

```
triples = do
  a <- [1..25]
  b <- [a..25]
  c <- [b..25]
  guard (p a b c)
  return (a,b,c)
  where
    p a b c = a*a + b*b == c*c
```

For an explanation of what's going on, see my blog post [A programmable semicolon explained](http://gbacon.blogspot.com/2009/07/programmable-semicolon-explained.html).

Answer (score 2):

Guards in computer science typically refer to the Boolean expression that indicates that a looping construct should continue. For example (pardon the pun)

```
for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
  /* stuff */
```

Here, `i < N` is the guard.

It's difficult to answer your question more thoroughly without more information.